# How do you call a convention by which binary operator is an unary one returning another unary operator?

Tags: functions

How do you call a convention by which any binary operator is an unary one returning another unary operator?

$F(x,y)\equiv (F(x))(y)$

This convention is used in functional programming languages. I want to know what is the name of this convention and may be after which scientist it is named if it did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transforming a function $$f:A\times B\to C$$ into $$g:A\to (B\to C)$$ is referred to as [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). It is named after the mathematician [Haskell Curry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_Curry).